# Handling fatal error thrown by JNA methods

Tags: java, error-handling, jna

I've a Java web application that makes use of OCR functionality. It uses [Tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) - a JNA wrapper for Tesseract OCR Engine. This functionality is optional and a custom exception should be thrown if any issue happens with the native code.

The following is the extract from my code:

```
try{
    //Tess4j method call
}catch(Throwable th){
    throw new CustomException("OCR engine failed to initialize.");
}
```

I've caught `java.lang.Throwable`(assuming both errors and exceptions in native implementation will be caught and thrown as CustomException).

However, it doesn't work as per my assumption. The web application server stops with below fatal error message containing some C code(pointers).

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f07205fc33a, pid=15040,
>   tid=0x00007f0723101700
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build
>   1.8.0_101-b13) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) Problematic frame: C 
>   [libtesseract.so.3.0.3+0x22533a]  ERRCODE::error(char const*,
>   TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x16a
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable
>   core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again The
>   crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. See
>   problematic frame for where to report the bug.

What could be the possible reason and how to fix this?

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: @Jorn - Updated my question with error message.

Comment: Segmentation faults are usually bugs. Check the documentation again, and check that what you're passing into the code conforms to the specs.

Comment: Ok. This behavior differs across platforms(works in Windows, but not in Linux). Does this mean that the bugs you mention are platform specific? Also, even if it's a bug, can't it be caught as an error?

Comment: This is a hardware exception caused by improper memory access. It is handled by the signal handler in the JVM, which produces the message that you see. Even if you were able to catch the error, you would not be able the recover from it any ways (hence "_fatal_ error"). If you can't solve it by passing different parameters, you could post an issue about it on the tesseract github, as it might be a bug.